# Writing a very basic search form in Django

Tags: python, html, django, search, django-forms

So I'm trying to get something very simple accomplished. I want to enter a term into my search box, and display it on the resulting page.

My HTML for the form is

```
<form method="get" action="/results/" class="navbar-form pull-right">
<input type="text" id="searchBox" class="input-medium search-query" name="q" placeholder="Search">
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search" >
</form>
```

The views.py looks like this:

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET['q']
    t = loader.get_template('template/results.html')
    c = Context({ 'query': query,})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

And finally the result template contains:

```
<div>You searched for: {{ query }} </div>
```

Here's the urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^home/$', 'search.views.home'),
url(r'^results/$', 'search.views.results'),
```

Nothing is showing up in the `{{ query }}` space.

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok so the action handling the search in your `views.py` is supposed to be `search` but as I suspected in your `urls.py` you don't call the `search` method anywhere.

Where do you execute `search` method?

Urls should be like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^home/$', 'search.views.home'),
url(r'^results/$', 'search.views.search'),
# or at least have a url for the search view
```

**Note the action attribute in your form**

It is `action="/results/"`. This means result view is the one who is supposed to be handling the form. You may also change this to `action="/search/"` and have your urls like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^home/$', 'search.views.home'),
url(r'^results/$', 'search.views.results'),
url(r'^search/$', 'search.views.search'),
```