# django search field redering a request from another site url

Tags: python, django

How can i use django to create a search field that will be able to perform a request from another website and render back some information from the site. for example if i submit this form number (PGA1512194112) on the search field, the app will be able to go to https://mis.unijos.edu.ng/pg/admissions/, search for PGA1512194112 and return back PGA1512194112's fullname, form number, faculty, department, programme and session.

Example(this is not a demo) of the view

```
    def form(request):
        query = request.GET.get['q']
        if query is valid
            return HttpResponseRedirect(form2)
        else
            search page
        context = {'query': query}
        return render(request,'.html', context)
```

Note: I dont even have idea of how the format of the view will look like.

'        def form(request):

```
        if request.GET:
            url = 'URL'
            query = request.GET.get('q')
            resp = requests.post(url, data=query)
            print ('resp.content')
        else:
            query=''
        context = {'query': query, 'resp': resp}
        return render(request, 'library/terms.html', context)'
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you need this site permission to do that or the site's api.

Comment: Usually that is what API is used for, so that you have accessible endpoint that you can simple formated query and retrieve simple formated response. If you do not have this option you will probably have to send request using requests library and then parse response html with soup for particular value. Will be even more horrible if request is resolved using javascript (which it looks like on this site)

Comment: you should be able to do using the web scraping technique. There are lot of scraping techniques in python. try with `selenium` or `phantomjs` etc... You also see if there is any publicly published rest-api for the website.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, which I do not know if this is "legal" or not is:

Use `selenium` package to be able to input your text into the website search box, then selenium will be able to access the resulting webpage and finally you will be able to perform a request to the website using `url` package or whatever you want to retrieve the whole html from the website.

The information of the resulting webpage should always be in the same format so it shouldn't be too hard to parse it and retrieve only what you need. You can also use `beautifulsoup` to have more tools to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission to use their API, the following will work:

```
import requests

url = 'https://mis.unijos.edu.ng/pg/admissions/ajax/ajax_get_admission.php'
data = {
    'q': 'PGA1512194112'
}
resp = requests.post(url, data=data) 

print resp.content
```

This returns html, but it shouldn't be too hard to parse the resulting html to get the information you're looking for.

Comment: thank you for your comment. but am i to add the code to my view or where

Comment: Even if i can get something that will help me to determine if the form number exist in the php url. something like if number exist in https://mis.unijos.edu.ng/pg/admissions/ return to a form page else return to search page.

Comment: @LORDMILA This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904173/writing-a-very-basic-search-form-in-django
My code could go in a view, something like the `search` view in that example

Comment: the search link above is something similar to what i want but i dont know how to capture the url on the request.Get. An example of how to do that will be better. thank you

Comment: @LORDMILA Do you mean the url containing the results of the query? You don't need to capture the url to get the results. In my code above, resp.content contains the results of the query.

Comment: Am still confused of how to design the view. can you please show me how with a full example of how it should look like. thank you

Comment: I tried you sample above and its giving me the error below: ValueError at /forms/

The view peruse.views.form didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: '        def form(request):
       
         if request.GET:
          url = 'https://mis.unijos.edu.ng/pg/admissions/ajax/ajax_get_admission.php'
          query = request.GET.get('q')
          resp = requests.post(url, data=query)
          print ('resp.content')
         else:
          query=''
         context = {'query': query, 'resp': resp}
         return render(request, 'library/terms.html', context)'

Comment: I was wondering if the code will be in this format. but the code ontop is useless because is not functioning